# Glance will not authenticate the admin user

Tags: openstack

This is the Folsom release again, and I am going by the book.   I have gotten to the point where I am trying to validate the glance installation, but I cannot get any commands through.  In **glance-api.conf**, I have:

```
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_host = localhost
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = glance
admin_password = glance

[paste_deploy]
config_file = /etc/glance/glance-api-paste.ini
flavor=keystone
```

in the **glance-registry.conf** file I have very similar:

```
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_host = localhost
auth_port = 35357
auth_protocol = http
admin_tenant_name = service
admin_user = glance
admin_password = glance

[paste_deploy]
config_file = /etc/glance/glance-registry-paste.ini
flavor=keystone
```

One background question:  is **glance** supposed to authenticate based on the username/password in the conf file(s) above, or is it supposed to ask **keystone** to authenticate?  I do have in the **keystone** data base a "glance" user with the same password but I can't tell if it is being used or not.

The failure I get looks like this:

```
root@osdemo:~# glance --debug --os_user=glance --os_password=glance index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/glance", line 1048, in <module>
    result = command(options, args)
  File "/usr/bin/glance", line 63, in wrapper
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/glance", line 559, in images_index
    print_header=True)
  File "/usr/bin/glance", line 501, in _images_index
    images = client.get_images(**parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/client.py", line 60, in get_images
    res = self.do_request("GET", "/images", params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/common/client.py", line 61, in wrapped
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/common/client.py", line 420, in do_request
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/common/client.py", line 75, in wrapped
    return func(self, method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/common/client.py", line 539, in _do_request
    raise exception.NotAuthenticated(res.read())
glance.common.exception.NotAuthenticated: You are not authenticated.
Details: 401 Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document 
you requested.  Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), 
or your browser does not understand how to supply the credentials required.

 Authentication required  
root@osdemo:~#
```

I am trying to review the configuration files, but I'm stuck.  Any help appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is better to use the bash rc file like the one below and source it to you current shell.

An example file (adminrc)  looks like the following

```
#!/bin/bash
# With the addition of Keystone, to use an openstack cloud you should
# authenticate against keystone, which returns a **Token** and **Service
# Catalog**.  The catalog contains the endpoint for all services the
# user/tenant has access to - including nova, glance, keystone, swift.
#
# *NOTE*: Using the 2.0 *auth api* does not mean that compute api is 2.0.  We
# will use the 1.1 *compute api*
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://keystone_server:5000/v2.0

# With the addition of Keystone we have standardized on the term **tenant**
# as the entity that owns the resources.
export OS_TENANT_ID=UUID_OF_THE_TENANT
export OS_TENANT_NAME=MY_TEST_TENANT

# In addition to the owning entity (tenant), openstack stores the entity
# performing the action as the **user**.
export OS_USERNAME=admin

# With Keystone you pass the keystone password.
echo "Please enter your OpenStack Password: "
read -s OS_PASSWORD_INPUT
export OS_PASSWORD=$OS_PASSWORD_INPUT
```

This can then be sourced to the current shell by

```
source adminrc
```

This file can be downloaded for a specific project from the settings option in horizon dashboard.

Comment: thanks as soon as I get to the office I will give this a try.

Comment: your suggestion helped but it wasn't the answer to my problem.  I have it working now but I am not sure what my problem was before.  I'll mark your answer so you get credit.

Comment: Marking this as correct is little help to future readers, as it doesn't address the problem in the question.